# Additional old_XXXXXXtaxonomy_term__field_XXX Tables after upgrading

Tags: 8, updating

After Upgrading from Drupal 8.6 to 8.7 I have tons of new (garbage?) tables in the database. The naming schema for the tables is old_XXXXXXtaxonomy_term__field_XXX

Is there a drush command to remove them or can i just drop dem directly?

I tried `drush eval "field_purge_batch(5000)"` and `drush entity-updates` without success.

Comment: The same happens for menu_link_content tables. it seems, that these are leftover tables when updating menus and taxonomies (as they are revisionable since 8.7)

Comment: As I found absolutely no functions which are referencing to these tables, I just deleted them. All went fine.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure there is an automatic way to do this, a manual way would be to use:

```
echo "Show tables;" | drush @alias sql-cli | grep old > drop_tables.sql
```

Edit the tables.txt file and add `drop table` and a ; after each table name.  Each line should look like:

```
drop table old_XXXXXXXtaxonomy_term__field_XXXX;
```

Backup you database in case Murphy come's around and do:

```
drush @alias sql-cli < drop_tables.sql
```

That will remove them from the DB.

Alternative way to do it via a GUI would be to use MySQL Workbench and drop them thru the interface.

Comment: thx for the reply. Deleting the tables is absolutely no problem. My main question is, if these tables are necessary in any way.

Comment: Drupal core and 99% of the contrib modules follow a pretty strict naming convention with the module owning the table used as a prefix.  Unless you have a module named old that is creating these, you can drop them.  But as with any major DB change, backup the database first.

Comment: A module is not the reason. This happened during Update to 8.7. The old tables do not have the fields for revisioning, die "normal" have it. Looks like a internal "backup" if the migrations does not work. The question is: who makes the garbage collection? Me as a dev or drupal itself?

Comment: Actually, the original question was _Is there a drush command to remove them or can i just drop dem directly?_ so this answer it. The question has never been _Are those table necessary?_ so the answer cannot answer to that.

Answer (score 0):

There is also another possibility how to delete the old_* tables:

```
drush sql-cli

SET @Drop_Stm = CONCAT('DROP TABLE ', (
  SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(TABLE_NAME) AS Old_Tables FROM information_schema.tables 
  WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'old_%'
)); 
PREPARE Stm FROM @Drop_Stm; 
EXECUTE Stm;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE Stm;
```

(Do not forget to back up your database before deleting the tables. ;-)